# Memory warnings in IPAD app with UITabbar of 8viewControllers

Tags: ipad

My application which is a UITabbar app has eight tabs. one tab for playing Audio, one for Playing Videos, one for Books(Leavesview is used for opening jpg image pages),one for Gallery.....so on.

So, Once I open all tabs the app throws memory warnings and crashes.
Then I did this: In each tabs viewController, I have allocated everything(views, imageViews.....) in ViewDidAppear method then I did removeFromSuperView and release in ViewDidDisappear method.Even then the problem persists.

Using Activity Monitor I observed that the app crashes when it exceeds 128 MB of Memory.
Each tab's ViewController is Occupying around 40MB memory. Even though I release everything in the ViewDidDisapper of the tab the memory is not freed but kept on increasing.

Is there anything regarding memory I have missed.  Please Help me resolve this ,   Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

I have noticed that when instantiating a UITabBarController it loads all it's dependencies and is really stubborn when trying to release an entire UIViewController. I've done a few things to combat this when I've had high memory UIViewControllers attached to a UITabBarController. What I suggest is only releasing the memory hog controls associated with each UIViewController on the ViewWillDisappear and re-Instantiating them on the ViewWillAppear rather than trying to release the entire UIViewController. Typically this is bad practice because you want to recycle as many of the controls as possible but if you have to stick with the UITabBarController this is the only way I've been successful.

If I misread your post and you aren't trying to release the UIViewController the I would need to see some code to figure out why things aren' releasing on ViewWillDisappear.

Comment: I did the same but used viewDidAppear and viewDidDisappear methods. In viewDidAppear I allocated all the subview and added to self.view, in viewDidDisappear I removed all the subviews from superview and released.